# Loop Compensation Design Case Study

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, switch-mode-power-supply, spice, pspice

I am understanding loop compensation to DC-DC voltage mode buck converter from this case study   [Compensation Case study](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~tymerski/chap1.pdf)

For example: I am simulating in PSpice Dominant Pole Compensation (Pg No 8 to 13) by using average model which I am assuming that is correct for ac analysis.

[image: Schematic]

- I am assuming error amplifier gain as `10k` here (Since this information was not provided)

[image: Bode Plot]

- Phase Margin of `90 Degree` and Gain crossover frequency of `74Hz` which almost matches with the document plot in Pg12.

Query: How to proceed with line transient using this above average mode in PSpice ?

Since I wanted to understand the transient responses w.r.t compensation.

Comment: You have an AC small signal model, which isn't suitable for transient simulation.  Get the transient model, use the same compensation and run your transient analysis on that.

Comment: Try to downlaod TIN-TI (Student version) a good SMPS simulator form Texas Instrument , they have a plenty of transient models of buck controllers, it will help you understand and simulate Line and Load transients